# Vertically Sliding CSS Background Image

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I noticed [this nice effect on Pinterest](https://it.pinterest.com/).

The background image scrolls vertically giving a sense that it's larger than the viewport. I tried playing with CSS with no luck.

HTML

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="inner">hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes scrollBgGridLinks {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-330px);
    }
}
.inner {
    animation: 35s linear 0s normal forwards 1 scrollBgGridLinks;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    clip:rect(0px, 50px, 50px, 0px);
    width:200px;
}
.out {
    height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pseudo Element Sliding Background

One or two background pseudo elements of `<body>` that are `position: fixed` with a height and width percentage.

To show elements above the background use this:

```
element-to-show-above {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

For pages with lots of content, it would make sense to apply the above properties to a wrapper that contains all your elements.

### Two examples

"Show code snippet" and run it to see the demo.

#### #1 - One slow transition to the top and pause

- The one pseudo element height is 200% the height and width of the viewport
- The background slides to -50% and pauses with the `forwards` option

**Note:** [Safari currently requires](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) the `-webkit-` prefix for the transform property.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
body:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: 80s bg linear forwards;
  animation: 80s bg linear forwards;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zawJr.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 300%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bg {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

#### #2 - The never ending background slideshow

1. Number one starts at 0 and slides to -100%.
2. Number two starts at 100% and slides to 0.

Together they form a constant motion illusion with no extra HTML needed!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
body:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: 5s bg linear infinite;
  animation: 5s bg linear infinite;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zawJr.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: 5s bg2 linear infinite;
  animation: 5s bg2 linear infinite;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zawJr.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bg {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bg2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
@keyframes bg2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Now it just depends... do you want it to constantly scroll or stop like Pinterest does? (I just noticed it stops) If it can stop, we can do this with one extra large background image and only one pseudo element.

Comment: Amazing thank you. I would like to it stop. How would it work?

Comment: The first example stops at 100% thanks to the `forwards` value. You just need a nice big image and you need to experiment with the number of seconds and the percentage width and height.

Comment: @misterManSam realized that this doesnt work on safari? may i know what's the issue?

Comment: @Slay - The `transform` property is only supported with the `-webkit-` prefix in Safari. I have added this to my examples. Place the prefixed version above the non-prefixed version like I have there.

Comment: @misterManSam thanks for the reply! I tried it. seems not working also. is it my safari version?

Comment: @Slay - The examples in my answer don't work either? What version of Safari do you have? [Transforms are supported since forever](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) with the prefix and [keyframes for a very long time as well](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes)